# How can i frame a SQL Case statement for the below case?

Tags: sql

I want to write a case statement to categorize users as engaged/ non engaged for example an engaged user is the one who books at least one order every 2 weeks. let say if someone booked the order 5 times in 10 weeks then he should be tagged as engaged.

```
No.of orders    weeks   user
2                10      A
3                12      B
4                8       C
5                10      D
6                8       E
```

According to requirements C,Dand E should be engaged and others non-engaged.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: So, you are saying that 50% booked (Orders / Weeks) or greater, then engaged, Else non engaged. `Case WHEN Orders / Weeks >= .5 THEN 'engaged' ELSE 'non engaged' END` If this is my correct understanding.

Comment: Why not user E?

Comment: I am sorry E should also be Engaged let me correct it.

Comment: @SS_DBA I would phrase it `Case WHEN Orders >= 2 * Weeks THEN 'engaged' ELSE 'non engaged' END` to avoid integer division but apart from that it's good.

Comment: @SS_DBA yes you are correct I guess

Comment: @TheImpaler, you mean `2 / Weeks`, correct? But I like your answer. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed table name as **tab** in the below query

```
 SELECT no_of_orders,weeks,user,CASE WHEN weeks/no_of_orders<=2 THEN 'engaged' ELSE 'non-engaged' END AS user_status FROM tab;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple case statement would be:

```
SELECT abc.*, CASE WHEN orders >= weeks/2 THEN 'ENGAGED' else 'NOT ENGAGED' end status
 FROM table abc;
```

O/P:

```
   +--------+-------+---------+-------------+
| ORDERS | WEEKS | USER_NM |    STATUS   |
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+
| 2      | 10    | A       | NOT ENGAGED |
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+
| 3      | 12    | B       | NOT ENGAGED |
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+
| 4      | 8     | C       | ENGAGED     |
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+
| 5      | 10    | D       | ENGAGED     |
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+
| 6      | 8     | E       | ENGAGED     |
+--------+-------+---------+-------------+
```